# Display Popup from postgis db over WMS layer file using leaflets?

Tags: geoserver, javascript, leaflet, wms, popup

i want to display popup information over WMS service file that i published from geoserver and using it Leaflets. Below is the picture for illustration.
[image]

Now i just want when user click any polygon the information related to it will be display as popup from postgis database, what are the possible ways to fetch information db ?

I am new to WebGIS.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a GeoServer WMS service, then the most straightforward way is to use the `getFeatureInfo` capabilities of the WMS protocol. See https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms and http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html#wms-getfeatureinfo

Comment: Thanks lvanSanchez,... but if i also want to display other information related to each polygon in popups from Postgresql DB rather then PostGIS then what are the options ?. I want to display small picture related to each polygon and some attribute information which is stored in RDBS.  Thank you

Comment: If you want to rely on your WMS: Click on map → get some ID of the polygon where the user clicked → use that ID to request the picture → display the picture.

Comment: Okay thank you very much lvanSanchez, let me try this thing,

Comment: I tried above provided link for info, but nothing happens. Whenever i use GetFeatureInfo function my WMS layers don't appear, i am using leaflets. Can you please help me ?